# How do I stop the glSurfaceView when I used finish() in my android apllication

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, activity-finish

So I am making an android game, and so far it's working fairly well. I was using System.exit(0) to kill it, but I know that is an improper way to do it. So I used finish() instead, which does close the program. The problem is, that when I reopen it, the screen is blank. It seems that for some reason, the glSurfaceView isn't being released, and continues to run, and that upon reopening the game, it loses focus of it? The sounds and everything play, and my Logcats display information, so the game is in fact running, but just not the screen. Now before people start jumping on the (just let android take care of closing your app bandwagon) I have my reasons for doing so. For one, telling me that android is efficient enough to do this is a lie, otherwise we would not have the need to restart the devices every other day. Nothing more bothersome that a lag driven phone that can barely even handle an incoming call because it has so much shit on it running. So yea, I would like to be able to close the app. 
So yea, how does one correctly to the glSurfaceView that it is time to close itself down? or to tell the Activities class that it needs to release it's handle to the glSurfaceView since closing the app sure doesn't do that.

Comment: You should post more of your code.

Comment: Are you calling the GLSurfaceView's `onPause()` and `onResume()` according to your activity's callbacks?

Comment: (1) Please don't use stackoverflow as a hosting site for OS rants.  (2) The GLSurfaceView and associated resources are torn down when the activity pauses; if it's coming up blank it's because it wasn't properly reconstructed when the app resumed.  (3) For a working example of a small but complete game using GLSurfaceView, see https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/ .

Comment: Okay guys, I figured out what my problem was.. By the way, sorry for taking forever to get back to this, and sorry for posting an upset question. 

It turns out that what I thought was the problem wasn't the problem at all. 
So to anyone that is having problems with your screen not loading properly when you reopen the game, Any -STATIC- variables stay in memory. So they held references to graphics data that was no longer in memory, even though the game had been completely closed and reopened as android doesn't always destroy things right away. So moral, check your static variables!